# window.open create reference to the name based

Tags: javascript

This way I get the reference to the open window:

```
var refWin = window.open("mypage1", "name_mypage");
```

if you want to close the window, I close with:

```
refWin.close();
```

if I do a screen refresh (F5) and run the same line, it opens in the same window, because I put the same name.

```
var refWin = window.open("mypage2", "name_mypage");
```

but with different reference (refWin).

Question: how I can make reference to the window based on the name?, I need to close the window before opening, with the same name.

do something like:

```
var refWin = window.open("about:blank", "name_mypage");
refWin.close();
refWin = window.open("mypage2", "name_mypage");
```

but without having to be a blank window for reference.

thanks

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, you want to be able to open a window, refresh the page (F5), and then close the window. Is that correct?

Comment: but why to close and reopen it? you can resize/change location without closing it

Comment: @Ryan Kinal, I need to open a new page (or image) in the same window and make the focus.
if I open one with the same name, change the website but does not focus on the window.
For that reason need to close the window. but prefer not to open a new window to only have to close.
As can be referenced by the same name by opening a new one, I'd like to do this but only to close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my solution based on another script:

```
Helper.window = new function () {

    // Private fields
    var w = window, s = screen, _self = this, whs = {}, isChrome = /chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());

    // Public Members
    this.focus = function (wh) {
        if (!wh) return;
        if (isChrome) wh.blur();
        wh.focus();
    };

    this.windowExists = function (wt) {
        return wt && whs[wt] && (typeof whs[wt]['closed'] != undefined) && !whs[wt].closed;
    };

    this.close = function (wt) {

        if (typeof whs[wt][close] != undefined) whs[wt].close();
        whs[wt] = null;

        return _self;
    };

    this.properties = function (wp) {

        wp = (wp || 'menubar=yes').toLowerCase();

        if (!(/menubar/.test(wp)))
            wp += 'menubar=yes';

        if (!(/location/.test(wp)))
            wp += ',location=yes';

        if (!(/width/.test(wp)))
            wp += ',width=' + (s.availWidth - 150);

        if (!(/height/.test(wp)))
            wp += ',height=' + (s.availHeight - 150);

        if (!(/scrollbars/.test(wp)))
            wp += ',scrollbars=yes';

        if (!(/resizable/.test(wp)))
            wp += ',resizable=yes';

        return wp;
    };

    this.open = function (url, wt, wp) {

        if (_self.windowExists(wt))
            return _self.close(wt).open(url, wt, wp);

        var urlOpen = '';
        if (typeof url == 'string') {
            urlOpen = url;
        } else if (jQuery(url).get(0).tagName.toLowerCase() == 'a') {
            urlOpen = jQuery(url).attr('href');
        } else {
            urlOpen = 'about:blank';
        }

        wp = _self.properties(wp);
        wt = wt || "_blank";

        var wh = wp ? w.open(urlOpen, wt, wp) : w.open(urlOpen, wt);

        if (wh && "_blank" !== wt) {
            whs[wt] = wh;
            _self.focus(wh);
        }

        return wh;
    };

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on andres's comment, here is the solution he's looking for:

```
refWin.location = "myurl";
refWin.focus();
```

This will open "myurl" in the window, and focus it.

Or.

```
var refWin = window.open("mypage1", "name_mypage");
refWin.focus();
```

**Edit:**

If you're not reloading the page again, there shouldn't be any reason you can't just do this:

```
var refWin = window.open("mypage1", "name_mypage");
refWin.close();
refWin = window.open("mypage1", "name_mypage");
```

If you're really concerned about it, you could make your own "windows" object:

```
var windows = {};
var refWin = window.open("mypage1", "name_mypage");
windows[refWin.name] = refWin;
windows("name_mypage").close();  // close the window
```

I don't think that's terribly productive, as you still can't focus it reliably, but maybe it fits your uses.

Comment: "refWin.focus();" (windows) only makes the window flashes, but does not force the focus on this, if it is open

Comment: Hmm. I wonder if that has to do with Windows settings. On my machine, it causes the window to gain Focus (Windows XP SP3) Is there any reason you can't just call window.open() again? See edits.